# Call a function based on the element dropped in jquery?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Hi all i have an drag and drop function where on drop i call a funciton for data binding

```
   function droppable(selector)
   {
      $("#dock").droppable({
         drop: function(event, ui) {
              var container=this; 
          GetAppender(ui.draggable,container);
           AppendData();
         }
        });
    }

    GetAppender(obj,container)
    {
       var Appender=""; 
       var ID= $(obj).attr('id');   
            switch(ID){
            case '1':
            $(container).append('<div id="images"></div>');
            break;
           case '2':
            $(container).append('<div id="tabs"></div>');
            } 
          //there may be several cases not only these two    

    }

    function AppendData()
    {
      if($('#images').length){ loadimages();}
      if($('#tabs').length){ loadimages();}
      //there are several funcitons to be loaded
    }
```

the above is my drag and drop funcitons i am using my concern here is that when i drop and image and it goes to case 1 in switch case and appends that div to the dropped area.. and then in my drop funciton i have AppendData() function in which i check the elements length if there is an div with image id i am execution loadimages funciton

after this if firstly i drop images and in my append data since the length of images div exists this method gets executed
            if($('#images').length){ loadimages();}

when i drop another tabs one now the issues starts there is already a div with images length so when i drop other one the length of both conditions satisy and both methods in my function AppendData() are executed ...can any one help me solving this issue please..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your problem as my propositions are so basic...

Maybe just use else statement:

```
function AppendData()
{
  if($('#images').length){ loadimages();}
  else if($('#tabs').length){ loadimages();}
  //there are several funcitons to be loaded
}
```

Or better:

```
function AppendData()
    {
      if($('#images').length || $('#tabs').length){ loadimages();}
    }
```

Comment: as i said what will i do if there are more than 10 cases i should be using 10 if else statements fro this

Comment: You should then pass param to AppendData(myparam) based on your switch statement